# lite-server with BrowserSync hosted on Heroku production ready?

Tags: angular, production, browser-sync, lite-server

I currently have an Angular 2 project that I'm trying to use for production hosted on heroku. It is currently being hosted on heroku and the start script heroku uses is:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w"
}
```

My bs-config.js looks like so:

```
module.exports = {
port: process.env.PORT || 8000,
files: ['./**/*.{html,htm,css,js}'],
server:{
    baseDir: "./"
},
open: false,
notify: false,
ghostMode: false
};
```

It all works well and fine, but I've read that you aren't supposed to use browsersync for production nor are you supposed to use lite-sever. My question is, if so, why not, and what additional steps can I take to make the angular 2 app production ready? Thanks!